# How to compose and execute column-oriented queries in yugabyte?

Tags: yugabytedb

How to compose and execute column-oriented queries in yugabytedb to support data science operations.

Comment: "data science operation" is vague. Can you be more specific regarding which function/queries you're interested ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to select just the subset of columns in your query, not sure if that is what you're asking about though.

If you're checking about YugabyteDB storing data in columnar format (as opposed to row format) - we currently do not support that. Could you please open a GitHub issue for that on our main repo?

Comment: Please add column format data storing feature, as optional, would be very helpful in data analysis!

Comment: Makes sense! Could you please open a GitHub issue so you can subscribe to updates as well, thanks!

Comment: opened issue #3409 to add column format data storing feature, as optional, would be very helpful in data analysis